# .htaccess Correctly Forward 404

Tags: .htaccess

I found different solutions on the web for solving 404 issues:

**Question:**
Is there a difference between solution 1 & 2 from a SEO perspective? Do I need R=404 on solution 1, or is it just fine for search engines if I forward to the 404?

**Solution 1 - A**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/? [L,QSA]
```

This solution displays the 404 page but it shows status code 200. So I was wondering if this has any disadvantages over:

**Solution 1 - B**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/? [R=404,L,QSA]
```

**Solution 2**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

Which shows also the 404 page but does throw the 404 response header.

EDIT SOLVED

***Force 404 on other error codes***
Also I have a lot of pages with 300 error which I would like to tell google that they actually don't exist. So I used the second strategy:

```
ErrorDocument 300 /404/
```

*But this time it keeps the 300 error code. Is there a way to force the 404 code because these requested pages don't exist any more.*

Solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/? [R=404,L,QSA]
```

Comment: `300-399` status codes are *not* errors.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem with **Solution 2**?

Comment: Actually I didn't really find a problem with solution 2. I was just wondering if solution 1 and 2 make a difference from a SEO perspective. I also found that on solution 1 it is possible to add a status code with:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/? [R=404,L,QSA]`

Comment: With the 300-399 they are mentioned in the google webmaster tools as soft 404. Also because no page exists I guess there should be some error behaviour. I now fixed it with Solution 1 and adding the `R=404 Code`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/? [R=404,L,QSA]` will sure return status 404 but won't load your `/404/` URL.